# Avaliação de código: Regressão logística com validação K fold. Está correto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aprendizagem-de-máquina, sklearn

O código abaixo é uma tentativa de fazer uma regressão logística com validação cruzada k fold. A ideia é pegar as matrizes de confusão geradas em cada fold e depois gerar uma matriz de confusão média, com 95% de confiança (intervalo de confiança para a média de 95%).

O código está fazendo sentido? Alguma sugestão de melhoria/correção?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from scipy.stats import sem, t
from scipy import mean

lista_matrizes = []


UNSW = pd.read_csv('/home/sec/Desktop/CEFET/UNSW_NB15_testing-set.csv')

previsores = UNSW.iloc[:,UNSW.columns.isin(('sload','dload',
                                                   'spkts','dpkts','swin','dwin','smean','dmean',
'sjit','djit','sinpkt','dinpkt','tcprtt','synack','ackdat','ct_srv_src','ct_srv_dst','ct_dst_ltm',
 'ct_src_ltm','ct_src_dport_ltm','ct_dst_sport_ltm','ct_dst_src_ltm')) ].values


classe= UNSW.iloc[:, -1].values

#iris = datasets.load_iris()
#print(iris.data.shape, iris.target.shape)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(
previsores, classe, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)

print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
#((90, 4), (90,))
print(X_test.shape, y_test.shape)
#((60, 4), (60,))

logmodel = LogisticRegression()
logmodel.fit(X_train,y_train)
print(previsores.shape)

#clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(X_train, y_train)
print(logmodel.score(X_test, y_test) ) 


#Computing cross-validated metrics

logmodel = LogisticRegression()
scores = model_selection.cross_val_score(
    logmodel, previsores, classe, cv=30)

print(scores)                                             
#array([ 0.96...,  1.  ...,  0.96...,  0.96...,  1.        ])
#print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))

########K FOLD
print('########K FOLD########K FOLD########K FOLD########K FOLD')
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

kf = KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
kf.get_n_splits(previsores)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(previsores):

    X_train, X_test = previsores[train_index], previsores[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = classe[train_index], classe[test_index]

    logmodel.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print (confusion_matrix(y_test, logmodel.predict(X_test)))

    lista_matrizes.append(confusion_matrix(y_test, logmodel.predict(X_test)))


#print(lista_matrizes)

final = np.mean(lista_matrizes, axis=0)
print(f" Mean confidence Matrix  \n{final}")


# o intervalo de confiança
def mean_confidence_interval(data, confidence=0.95):

    #data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    n = len(data)
    m = mean(data)
    std_err = sem(data)
    h = std_err * t.ppf((1 + confidence) / 2, n - 1)

    start = m - h
    #print (start)


    end = m + h
    #print (end)

    return start, end




print()
print(f"Intervalo de confiança: \n{mean_confidence_interval(final)}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu código esta correto. 
Porem meio bagunçado. pelo que você explicou no enunciado da pergunta não é necessário a primeira parte acima do k-fold.
Outro conselho é importar as libs todas no inicio do código pois assim não gera confusão.

Eu geralmente transformo esses procedimentos em funções para criar um Pipeline para gerar relatórios para futuros modelos.
Outra coisa interessante de avaliar no seu código é o:

```
sklearn.metrics.classification_report
```

Essa função retorno um relatório contendo, precissão, recall e f1-score sõa métricas extremamente importantes para problemas de classificação.
Nome das variáveis e cometários funcionais: é importante definir bem, pois a medida que seu código for crescendo você pode acabar não conseguindo mais aproveitar o que fez.